# Error while cloning project from bitbucket

Tags: git

When i tried to clone my project from bitbucket i am facing following error.
Please help me solve it.

1. I have created one folder in c drive
2. copy the clone repository path from bitbucket count
3. using git bash try to clone the project by pasting copied path of repository

While doing these steps i am facing following error

```
error: RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Comment: Sounds like _something_ unexpectedly closed your connection. Could be Bitbucket itself, but more likely it's a proxy or firewall on your own machine or in between you and Bitbucket.

Comment: Thank you for response. I was stop firewall protection but still i am facing the error.

Comment: My problem is solved using git clone https://gitexample.com/group/test.git --depth 1 this command thank you

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved using `git clone gitexample.com/group/test.git --depth 1`. Thank you